# How Leaflet makes request to get the tile image

Tags: leaflet

I have used Leaflet in my web app for a while. And I studied the source code, but didn't find the code or function for sending HTTP request. If I missed the code, which part is for this function?

If it is not done in the Leaflet level, and how does it work? How does the Leaflet.js and server communicate with each other?

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L137) where Leaflet "requests" the tile:

```
createTile: function (coords, done) {
    var tile = document.createElement('img');
```

It doesn't request the tile, it just creates an `<img>` element, and the browser does the actual request for the image source.